# LD_LIBRARY_PATH set in build.rs is not passed to the debugger in vscode

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, rust, shared-libraries

So I have two simple projects one that has a sub-folder with a c-library that it links to at runtime and the other is just a brand new hello-world app.

I was watching this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzQ7YIIo1rY&t=3386s really good tutorial video and I was looking at setting up vscode with rust plugins.

So I installed `rust analyser` and `CodeLLDB`. Both are working great on both projects. So far so good. Then I wanted to run the `debug` option just above the `fn main() {` line of code. This worked perfectly for the simple hello world app. For the app that also links to a shared object library it tries to run but I get the error:

```c
/home/user/bbb/development/rust_test/target/debug/rust_test: error while loading shared libraries: libadd_x64Linuxd.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Which I am not very surprised about, in other debuggers for C++ I have to setup a settings/launcher.json and just add the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in there. But for rust I am not so sure. I would have thought the `build.rs` would have taken care of that - which contains:

```rust
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    // EXTERN_C
    // The name of the library to link to, i.e. like: -l<lib>
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=dylib=add_x64Linuxd");
    // The library search path for linking, i.e. like -L<path>
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native=cadd/lib");
    // The run-time library search path (LD_LIBRARY_PATH)
    println!("cargo:rustc-env=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=cadd/lib");
}
```

So the paths are all set in here. `cargo run` works and it links to my shared library. So the question is how do I pass/setup the LD_LIBRARY_PATH when running the debugger (just as show in the youtube video by pressing the in-code "debug" option)?

Comment: Hi, do you find any answer to the question? I'm stuck at this point

Comment: Unfortunately no, not yet. I moved on to other things and have not gotten back to look into this since : (